# quill Overwriting formats/div with?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Why am I getting a warning in the console, my codes are as follows?

Quill.tagName = 'DIV'; I used the line nothing changed.

```
    import '@vueup/vue-quill/dist/vue-quill.core.css';
    import '@vueup/vue-quill/dist/vue-quill.snow.css';
    import '@vueup/vue-quill/dist/vue-quill.bubble.css';
    
    import { QuillEditor, Quill } from '@vueup/vue-quill'
    import htmlEditButton from "quill-html-edit-button";
    Quill.register("modules/htmlEditButton", htmlEditButton);
    
    
    export default {
        name: "Edit",
        components: { ValidateError, QuillEditor },
        props: {
            dat: Object,
        },
        data(){
            return {
                submitted: false,
                editorOption: {
                    modules: {
                        clipboard: {
                            matchVisual: false
                        },
                        toolbar: [
                            ["bold", "italic", "underline", "strike"],
                            [{ header: [!1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] }, "blockquote", "code-block"],
                            [{ list: "ordered" }, { list: "bullet" }, { indent: "-1" }, { indent: "+1" }],
                            [{ align: [] }],
                            ["link"],
                            ["clean"],
                        ],
                        htmlEditButton: {},
                    },
                    placeholder: "Write...",
                },
            }
        },
    }
```

I am getting warnings like below in console. I've been struggling for 2 days and I couldn't get rid of this error message.

```
    quill Overwriting formats/div with
    
    function e()​
        allowedChildren: Array(29) [ e(), e(), e()
        , … ]
        blotName: "div"
        length: 0
        name: "e"
        prototype: Object { constructor: e()
        }
        tagName: "DIV"
    <prototype>: function e(t)
```